# Keeping a maximum length array, how do I remove old x length of old data while pushing in new data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a dataset coming in from an api like so:

```js
  samples: [
    {
      key: 'I',
      values: [
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
        // ....
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'I',
      values: [
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -100.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.3334 },
        // ....
      ],
    },
    {
      key: 'I',
      values: [
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
        { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
        // ....
      ],
    },
  ]
```

To which I need to have a flat array like so:

```js
const newData = [
  [
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
    // ....
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -100.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 5.3334 },
    // ....
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -37.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: -32.1234 },
    { timing: '12356timingdatething', reading: 1.1234 },
    // ....
  ]
```

and I've achieved this via using reduce:

```js
this.setState((prevState) => ({
            activeGraphData: jsonData.samples.reduce((_, c) => [...prevState.activeGraphData, ...c.values] as any, [])});
```

however, now I want to be able to limit this array to a length about X, which in my case is `1000`. While limiting it, as new data comes in, I want to be able to remove the old data to make way for said new data. My thought process is to basically:

1. Turn data in a flat array of objects
2. Return old data + new data in new Array and set the state
3. if the length is >= 1000, take the new data's `length` and remove that amount of elements in the beginning of the array, and set the state.
4. repeat and keep a fix rate of 1000 at all times.

So far in implementing this, this is what I have:

```js
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            activeGraphData: jsonData.samples.reduce((_, c) => {
                if (prevState.activeGraphData.length >= 1000) {
                    return [
                        ...prevState.activeGraphData.slice(
                            prevState.activeGraphData.length,
                            -c.values.length
                        ),
                        ...c.values,
                    ];
                }

                return [...prevState.activeGraphData, ...c.values] as any;
            }, []),
        }));
```

sadly this doesn't work.

Could anyone check if I'm on the right track? and is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prevState.activeGraphData.slice(
    prevState.activeGraphData.length,
    -c.values.length
)
```

is wrong, since you get nothing from passing those values:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8];

console.log(arr1.slice(arr1.length, -arr2.length));
```

Instead you need

```
prevState.activeGraphData.slice(c.values.length)
```

That will take `c.values.length` items off from the beginning:

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8];

console.log(arr1.slice(arr2.length));
```

---

Finally, the whole `return` statement can be simplified from:

```
return [
    ...prevState.activeGraphData.slice(c.values.length),
    ...c.values,
];
```

to

```
return prevState.activeGraphData
    .slice(c.values.length)
    .concat(c.values);
```

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8];

console.log(
  arr1
    .slice(arr2.length)
    .concat(arr2)
);
```

---

Alternatively, you can just combine the two array and pass a negative value to `.slice()` to get *up to* that amount of items which removes the need for an `if` check:

```
return prevState.activeGraphData
    .concat(c.values)
    .slice(-1000);
```

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const arr2 = [6, 7, 8];

console.log(
  arr1
    .concat(arr2)
    .slice(-5)
);

console.log(
  [1]
    .concat(arr2)
    .slice(-5)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```